# Computed Property as Summary in Lightswitch

Tags: visual-studio-lightswitch, computed-field

I'm creating a Lightswitch project where I have a table of users. The table has FirstName and LastName columns, but when selecting users in other controls I want to display "Firstname LastName".

I've created a computed "FullName" field which concatenates the two fields, but when I selected this field as the summary property, controls listing users still show the first real string property found.

I'm guessing this has something to do with the FullName field not being a *real* field. Is there a way to make the FullName field a real field, which updates automatically when FirstName or LastName changes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out the drop down I was using was just the property selector, not the summary property. I wasn't seeing the summary property field because I had server selected at the bottom rather then client.

Answer (score 0):

From the '*It works for me*' dept.

I have the same trouble.  A user field was always coming up with 'username' (eg \MACHINE\login), instead of my computed property (which I even called 'Summary' so LS would be happy) comprising Firstname, " ", and Surname.

I was aware of the fact, but it took your comment: "the first real string property" to drive home why my field wasn't changing.  So, in the table designer, I just moved the summary property/field to be the first real string property.  It is not intuitively obvious that you can do this.  I found the easiest way was to select a different field, and then, in one mouse action, click/press and drag the Summary field to its correct location.

Problem solved.